# I made a invoice using angular 11 but i cannot calculate total and total amount

Tags: angular

[image]In this case i want to get total value in item details section one by one when input item , and also i want to calculate Total Amount of all input items. I try lot of methods , but i cannot do this so how can i do this??

my home.component.html file is,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" >INVOICE</a>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid pt-2" style="margin-bottom: 250px">

      <div class="card border-secondary">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Invoice Details</h4>
          <form #invoiceinformation="ngForm" >
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Issued Person Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" ngModel>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Invoice Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" ngModel>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="invoiceNo">Invoice No</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoiceNo" id="invoiceNo" ngModel>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="TAmount">Total Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="totalAmount" id="TAmount" ngModel>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card border-secondary mt-2 mb-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between">Items Details <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRow()" >+</button></h4>


          <form action="" #invoiceBody="ngForm">
            <div *ngFor="let obj of itemsArray;let i=index">
          <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Item No</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemNo{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.itemNo" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Unit Price</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="unitPrice{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.unitPrice">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Quantity</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.quantity">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <label>Total</label>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="i!=0">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top:30px" (click)="removeRow(i)">-</button>
            </div>



           </div>

          </div>


          </form>


          </div>

        </div>



'
      <button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="addInvoiceInformation(invoiceinformation);addInvoiceBody()" >Add To Database</button>



</div>
```

my home.component.ts file is,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'



class itemObject {
  itemNo:any;
  unitPrice:any;
  quantity:any
 
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

itemObject=new itemObject()
itemsArray=[
  {itemNo:"",unitPrice:"",quantity:""}
]




  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.itemsArray)
  }



  addInvoiceInformation(invoiceinformation: any) {
       console.log(invoiceinformation.value)
  }

  addInvoiceBody() {

  console.log(this.itemsArray)


  }

  addRow() {
    this.itemsArray.push(this.itemObject)


  }

  removeRow(i: number) {
    this.itemsArray.splice(i)
  }
}
```

**Plz help me to do this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach could be improved, but for your current approach I think this does it.

Update itemObject class

```
class itemObject {
  itemNo: any;
  unitPrice: number = 0;
  quantity: number = 0;
}

......

itemsArray: Array<itemObject> = [
    { itemNo: "", unitPrice: 0, quantity: 0 }
  ]
```

Add two methods to calculate totals

```
 getInvoiceTotal() {
    return this.itemsArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc += this.getItemTotal(item);
      return acc;
    }, 0)
  }

  getItemTotal(item: itemObject) {
    return (item.quantity && item.unitPrice) ? item.quantity * item.unitPrice : 0;
  }
```

And update your tempate on the invoice part

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="TAmount">Total Amount</label>
              <span>{{getInvoiceTotal()}}</span>
            </div>
```

And for each item

```
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <label>Total</label>
              <span>{{getItemTotal(obj)}}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: how can i update my itemsArry accourding to this getItemTotal() functions return value ?????

Comment: you want to save the total of each item in the item object?

Comment: bro, i console log my total but i cannot console log my total amount, can u suggest a method for me to console log my total amount???

Comment: @upul I am not undestanding you... Be more specific please.
Still... to save the total for each itemObject
`<input (change)="updateItem(i)" type="number" class="form-control" name="unitPrice{{i}}"
                [(ngModel)]="obj.unitPrice">`
and
`<input (change)="updateItem(i)" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity{{i}}"
                [(ngModel)]="obj.quantity">`

and create method
`updateItem(i: number) {
    this.itemsArray[i].total = this.getItemTotal(this.itemsArray[i])
  }`

Comment: bro i got total earlier, but this problem belongs to total amount not total

Comment: I can get the value of total amount of this getInvoiceTotalAmount() function. but i still cannot console log this value always comming empty..

Comment: Ok. Can you update your question code to reflect that? and we go from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231619/discussion-between-upul-and-kitsune66).